# How to Enable Flash Plugin in Webview on API 20?

Tags: android, android-webview

I used this code enable the plugins for the webview, but It dose not support in API 20

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Adobe has not supported Flash on Android for years.

Comment: how to play fly video in latest android api??